# Preventing the collapsed Bootstrap Nav from wrapping the Brand?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

My problem is pretty straightforward. I would post an image, but I don't have enough rep. On an extra-small screen, independent of Brand size or media query, the navbar (collapse) will wrap the Brand and form another visible row on screen.

Using Bootstrap 3 and Rails 4. Here is my navbar partial:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand brandup" href="/">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/Skillsesh_Horizontal.png" style="height: 40px;" />
        </a>
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I made a Bootply for you at http://www.bootply.com/XOXD3JbUgw just in case, but I really don't understand what do you want to achieve, because this behavior you mention happens at around 150px, and I doubt you'll ever found a 150px screen. At least not one anyone would use to navigate a web site. The option is to add a nowrap or block the whole nav so you will have horizontal scrolling, which is 10x worse by any means, but maybe I'm not understanding correctly, so there you have the Bootply so you can explain it.

Comment: Also, if you want to post an image, just post it as code and someone will edit it so it looks as a link